# github actions: how to access badges?

Tags: python, github-actions, badge

This documentation explains how workflows generate badges, and how to access them:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge

in short:

> https://github.com///actions/workflows/<WORKFLOW_FILE>/badge.svg

But I have a job that generates two badges. In my particular case:

- the "default" workflow badge
- a test coverage badge, generated by pytest-coverage

Here my pytest.yaml file:

```
name: Unit tests

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version-file: '.python-version'
          cache: 'pip'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install pytest pytest-coverage
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest --cov
      - name: Coverage Bagdge
        uses: tj-actions/coverage-badge-py@v1.8
```

the workflow is successfull, and the github actions page reports:

> saved badge to /home/runner/work/REPO-NAME/REPO-NAME/coverage.svg

Do I need to fix the workflow to move the badge somewhere? Or is there already a link I can use to access coverage.svg ? (I just want to display the badge in the readme of the repository)

note: the link to `pytest.yaml/badge.svg` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This action helps:

https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action

I created the (orphan) "coverage-badge" branch and updated the workflow:

```
name: Unit tests

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version-file: '.python-version'
          cache: 'pip'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install pytest pytest-coverage
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest --cov
      - name: Creating coverage folder
        run: |
          mkdir -p coverage
      - name: Coverage Bagdge
        uses: tj-actions/coverage-badge-py@v1.8
        with:
          output: coverage/coverage.svg
      - name: Publish coverage report to coverage-badge branch
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          branch: coverage-badge
          folder: coverage
```

As a result, coverage.svg is commited to the coverage-badge branch, and I can add this to the README.md:

```
![code coverage](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO/coverage-badge/coverage.svg?raw=true)
```

Comment: I am a newbie to the Github actions. I spent a day searching how to add coverage badge with percentage to my project without third party sites. Tried some 'solutions" but failed. Finally this answer worked. Thanks!

Comment: If you see "Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128", add 'permissions' to the job as mentioned here: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action